# Auto mount cd or dvd on CLI based ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, samba, automounting, data-cd

I am using Ubuntu server as a samba server. The solution I am looking for is whenever the disks are inserted (cd or dvd) they should get auto-mounted to `/cdrom` directory. Are there any tools for achieving this? I installed ivman, and it is running as a daemon. But it is doing nothing.

EDIT 1: Tried autofs, and it doesn't work as well. There is a bug report on launchpad which suggests that autofs for lucid is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would go the autofs-route. But as you stated autofs might be broken on Lucid (I'm not an Ubuntu-User).

You could also try udev-wrappers or rules. The Arch Linux wiki has something on that. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#UDisks

Comment: I have default udev rules like so: `SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.5-scsi-0:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="cdrom", ENV{GENERATED}="1"` But they are not working.